# How to get sequelize getter to work with findAll

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

For sake of example, I have this very simple model:

```
const Blog = sequelize.define(
  'Blog',
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      get() {
        return this.getDataValue('id').toString();
      }
    },
  },
)
```

I would like to return the id my records as strings, but it does not work:

```
const blogs = Blog.findAll({ raw: true })
console.log(blogs)
```

Returns a list of blogs with the id property as a number.

Any ideas why and if that's not the correct way to do this, what would it be?

Comment: You say that a primary key is a number but you indicated `type: DataTypes.STRING`. At least you should indicate as `type: DataTypes.INTEGER`

Comment: That's just an example, the point is that transformations don't happen with `.findAll`

Comment: Can you turn off `primaryKey` option and see if a `get` works or not

Comment: Remove `raw: true` - it's just returning the raw data from the database

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a different type for the primary key make sure to set `autoIncrement: false`. Typically you would use either a `DataTypes.INTEGER` or `DataTypes.UUID` as a primary key type but should work with a `DataTypes.String` as well. You will need to insert a unique value for each row.

If you want to run the getter you need to remove `raw: true`. When you specify raw results the columns that are returned from the database are mapped directly to a JSON object, in this case they are numeric. If you want to map the results back to a plain JSON object instead of Model Instances you can use `Array.map()` and `Instance.toJSON()`.

Note that in your example you omitted `await` or thenable syntax as well which is necessary to get the results asynchronously.

```js
const blogs = await Blog.findAll();
const plainObjs = blogs.map((blog) => blog.toJSON());
```